# Prevent auto duplicate append html

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to append HTML in multiple divs using classes. But my code is duplicating HTML in one section (HTML 1) when the another is all right.

**HTML 1:**

```
<div class="about-author">
  <div class="author-text">
    This is a author bio. <a href="https://example.com">example</a><a href="https://example.com">example</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**HTML 2:**

```
<div class="author-info">
  <div class="author-bio">
    This is a author bio. <a href="https://example.com">example</a><a href="https://example.com">example</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".about-author .author-text,.author-info .author-bio").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        link = $this.find("a");
    link.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            cls = $this.text().trim(),
            url = $this.attr("href");
        $this.replaceWith('<li class="' + cls + '"><a href="' + url + '" title="' + cls + '" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"/></li>')
    });
    if (link.length) {
        $this.parent().append('<ul class="author-links social social-color"></ul>');
    }
    $this.find("li").appendTo(".author-links")
});
```

I want the same output in HTML 1 and HTML 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly loop through the links..With this way no need to check for length because the loop will not work without `<a>` found in the divs

I believe there're some ways to do this but that's what it comes in my mind right now .. Check the next code

```js
$(".author-text a,.author-bio a").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    cls = $this.text().trim(),
    url = $this.attr("href");
    newLI = '<li class="' + cls + '"><a href="' + url + '" title="' + cls + '" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">'+ cls +'</a></li>';
    if(!$this.parent().find('.author-links').length){ // check to not append ul twice
      $this.closest('div').append('<ul class="author-links social social-color"></ul>'); // append the url
    }
    $this.parent().find(".author-links").append(newLI); // append the new li to the url
    $this.remove();  // remove the $this <a> element
});
```

```css
.author-links{
  background : #d2d2d2;
  padding : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="about-author">
  <div class="author-text">
    This is a author bio 1. 
    <a href="https://example.com">example 1</a>
    <a href="https://example.com">example 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="author-info">
  <div class="author-bio">
    This is a author bio 2. 
    <a href="https://example.com">example 3</a>
    <a href="https://example.com">example 4</a>
    <a href="https://example.com">example 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

AND By using `.next()` and `.after()` You can Show the ul after closest div

```js
$(".author-text a,.author-bio a").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    cls = $this.text().trim(),
    url = $this.attr("href");
    newLI = '<li class="' + cls + '"><a href="' + url + '" title="' + cls + '" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">'+ cls +'</a></li>';
    if(!$this.parent().next('.author-links').length){ // check to not append ul twice
      $this.closest('div').after('<ul class="author-links social social-color"></ul>'); // append the url
    }
    $this.parent().next(".author-links").append(newLI); // append the new li to the url
    $this.remove();  // remove the $this <a> element
});
```

```css
.author-links{
  background : #d2d2d2;
  padding : 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="about-author">
  <div class="author-text">
    This is a author bio 1. 
    <a href="https://example.com">example 1</a>
    <a href="https://example.com">example 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="author-info">
  <div class="author-bio">
    This is a author bio 2. 
    <a href="https://example.com">example 3</a>
    <a href="https://example.com">example 4</a>
    <a href="https://example.com">example 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how to show ul after closest div?